# Using a where clause on a newly created field

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, lateral-join

How do i perform a where action on a newly created field that is populated with the values of two fields?

```
select upper(column_a + ' ' + column_b) as newly_created_field,
some_other_field
from table_xyz
where newly_created_field = 'NEW VALUE'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to the alias in the `WHERE` clause at the same level as the `SELECT` in which it was defined.  Your options include repeating the entire expression in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT UPPER(column_a + ' ' + column_b) AS newly_created_field,
       some_other_field
FROM table_xyz
WHERE UPPER(column_a + ' ' + column_b) = 'NEW VALUE'
```

Or, you may subquery and then refer to the alias directly:

```sql
SELECT newly_created_field, some_other_field
FROM
(
    SELECT UPPER(column_a + ' ' + column_b) AS newly_created_field,
       some_other_field
    FROM table_xyz
) t
WHERE newly_created_field = 'NEW VALUE';
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I find that `cross apply` and `values` provide an elegant solution to the question.

You can compute the value once in the `from` clause, and then use it everywhere in the query (including the `where` clause):

```
select x.newly_created_field, t.some_other_field
from table_xyz t
cross apply ( values (upper(t.column_a + ' ' + t.column_b) ) x(newly_created_field)
where x.newly_created_field = 'NEW VALUE'
```